# How to delete a file with .txt extension from a directory using ruby script

Tags: ruby, directory

I want to delete all files present in `page/sanjay` directory with `.txt` extension.

I tried the following code

```
Dir.glob('/page/sanjay/*.txt').each { |file| File.delete(file)}
```

and got some error:

```
./newTrySanjay.rb: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `'/page/sanjay/*.txt''
./newTrySanjay.rb: line 1: `Dir.glob('/page/sanjay/*.txt').each { |file| File.delete(file)}'
```

Comment: The code looks OK to me and works in my local.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this to:

```
File.delete(*Dir.glob('/page/sanjay/*.txt'))
```

[`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-delete) accepts a list of filenames, and `*Dir.glob` will burst the array normally returned into that list.